# QSqlTableModel setFilter too many arguments

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qsqltablemodel

I'm trying to assign a signal to a pushbutton so that it calls a function which filters and shows specific data on tableView.
but when i click on the button it says:

```
Type error: setFilter(self, str) too many arguments
```

and the application crashes

assigning signal

```
self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(lambda : self.search(self.ui.lineEdit.text()))
```

```
def search(self,item):
    item = "%" + item + "%"
    self.model.setFilter('name LIKE ?',(item,))

    self.model.select()
```

but when there are no other parameters but `self` in `search()` it works

```
self.model.setFilter('name LIKE "John" ')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

setFilter() does not accept placeholders so you just have to concatenate:

```
def search(self,item):
    self.model.setFilter("name LIKE '%{}%'".format(item))
    self.model.select()
```